# Flutter jsondecode with map and list in the response

Tags: android, json, flutter, dart

I would like to fetch data from an API and decode that to a list:

Beginning of my model:

```
import 'dart:convert';

Summary summaryFromJson(String str) => Summary.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String summaryToJson(Summary data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Summary {
    final QuoteSummary quoteSummary;

    Summary({
        required this.quoteSummary,
    });

    factory Summary.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Summary(
        quoteSummary: QuoteSummary.fromJson(json["quoteSummary"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "quoteSummary": quoteSummary.toJson(),
    };
}

class QuoteSummary {
    final List<Result> result;
    final dynamic error;

    QuoteSummary({
        required this.result,
        required this.error,
    });

    factory QuoteSummary.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => QuoteSummary(
        result: List<Result>.from(json["result"].map((x) => Result.fromJson(x))),
        error: json["error"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "result": List<dynamic>.from(result.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "error": error,
    };
}

class Result {
...
```

With the following code I try to decode the json after getting the response from the API:

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final result = jsonDecode(response.body);

      return result.map((e) => QuoteSummary.fromJson(e));
    } else {
      throw Exception(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
  }
```

And here the beginning of the response body:

```
{
  "quoteSummary": {
    "result": [
      {
        "price": {
          "maxAge": 1,
          "preMarketChange": {},
```

But I get a:

```
_TypeError (type '(dynamic) => QuoteSummary' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform')
```

If I debug my application I can see the response is coming:

```
"{"quoteSummary":{"result":[{"summaryDetail":{"maxAge":1,"priceHint":{"raw":2,"fmt":"2","longFmt":"2"},"previousClose":{"raw":99.…"
```

How do I get the "result" in a list to work with in my ListView widget?

Comment: try adding .toList() in result.map((e) => QuoteSummary.fromJson(e));

Comment: I tried that with the same error message.

return result.map((e) => QuoteSummary.fromJson(e)).toList();

Answer (score 0):

Use `Summary.fromJson` parse after decode

```
final result = jsonDecode(response.body);
Summary.fromJson(result))
```

or directly `summaryFromJson` to decode and parse.

```
summaryFromJson(response.body);
```

Comment: I changed to:

final result = summaryFromJson(response.body);

return result.quoteSummary.result;

But running now in:

_TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>')